# Can Unity be used as an independent interface in a custom non-ubuntu build OS?

Tags: unity

I am working on a custom-build of 12.04 with OpenBox, on low-resource netbooks.

I have installed Unity, but it is not available at login, nor by any other apparent means, and I cannot find any coherent answers.

I want to use Unity as an interface, without having to install all the 'heavy' dependencies, such as Nautilus.

Is this possible, or is it necessary to use a full-weight, resource-hungry, standard Ubuntu installation?

---

I'm using lightdm.

Running gnome-session defeats the object: I've already removed as many lxde components to lighten the load.

I'd have liked to run unity on openbox, but the two don't seem to work together. I edited the startup script, and had to re-edit it from a live cd session. it was a close shave!!! Even running 'unity --replace' crashed the desktop to login.

I'll stick with openbox and tint2.

Comment: What does "at login" mean? Are you using lightdm? gdm? xdm? kdm? What exactly? You need `gnome-session` installed for the Ubuntu session to show up.

Comment: If you need a lightweight distro, Unity is not the right approach. LXDE is much more lightweight ([Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), made for low-spec machines, is Ubuntu modified to use LXDE).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are free to modify Unity in any way you choose. ↓

> #### Development
>
> Unity is **Open Source** , and we depend on our developer community to implement great design and fix bugs, raising the quality of Unity for our users.

<sup>Referenced from →https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/</sup>

Open Scource Definition:↓

> Generally, **open source** refers to a computer program in which the source code is available to the general public for use and/or modification from its original design.

<sup>Reference from →http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source</sup>

So yes you can modify it to be lightweight, or any weight you want it to be. But as **dobey** mentioned, I believe you have to have a gnome session to run it. Unless you modify it for something else... I guess.

I hope this answers your questions... Good Luck!

Comment: @Seth Thanks for the edit. I should have highlighted that, was spacing out I guess...

Comment: As a lightweight option, sadly modern Unity versions do not cut it.  They are as resource hungry as Gnome, if not more so. Unity 2D used to be fall back as a separate low resource options.  I am not sure where it stands now.